# Labelling points in a plot in Excel with customized label

Tags: microsoft-excel, charts

I want to label a plot's points in excel with neither the x nor the y variable but a label that is in a cell where the row happens to be. So for example, if I have the following table data:

```
1   1   a
2   4   b
3   8   c
4   16  d
5   32  e
```

I want the point `(1,1)` in the chart to be labeled as a in the plot, and the point `(5,32)` labelled as "e".

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft Support has a solution (article) exactly for your case:

[How to use a macro to add labels to data points in an xy scatter chart or in a bubble chart in Excel](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213750)